# Control embedded YouTube video by using JS

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have YouTube video embedded on my webpage. Can I control it by using JS?

I need to retrieve total length of the video and get events when user changes trackbar position (or position changed during playback).

Comment: Have you checked libraries like [video.js](https://videojs.com/) or [plyr.js](https://plyr.io/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to youtube embeds the Youtube Iframe Player API will supply most of the functions needed for controlling/monitoring events from an embedded youtube video (refer to [IFrame Player API
Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)).

If you want to get the length of the video you can use `player.getDuration()`, more details are available in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information).

In regards to trackbar events the API doesn't supply a direct way to monitor those events but there is a hacky way to do it as mentioned in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359341/how-to-catch-youtube-players-dragging-skipping-forwarding-event-with-api-in-jav).

Another way to achieve this is by using a 3rd-party library like [beaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4432208/beaver) mentioned in the comment section.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

#### Plyr.js

Using [Plyr.js](http://plyr.io/) you can control YouTube (and also Vimeo) video with a simple HTML5 media player with 3 steps:

1. [Embedding](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#youtube-embed) a YouTube video:

   `<div id="myVideo" data-type="youtube" data-video-id="4IP_E7efGWE"> </div>`
2. Getting player instance ([setup](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#initialising)):

   `var videoEl = $('#myVideo').get(),
     player = plyr.setup(videoEl);`
3. Handling [events](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#events) and using [methods](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#methods):

   `player[0].on('playing', function(event) {
       var instance = event.detail.plyr;
       console.log("  >playing");
       console.log("  >duration: " + instance.getDuration());
   });`

#### Example:

here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/2g5ggcfa/

Comment: Would it be within YouTube's copyright rules to wrap YouTube videos within this player?